# Mesos & persistent storage using MySQL

Tags: mysql, persistence, mesos, mesosphere

This is going to be a generic question.

We are a young startup faced with the inevitable problem of scaling and during our research, Apache Mesos seemed like a good fit for our architecture, which is –

- Core Scala based microservices, each responsible for dealing with a
  part of our database, which is mainly MySQL
- Middleware microservices,
  to deal with some other persistent data-storage systems like MongoDB,
  Elasticsearch etc.

Which basically means that we can containerise all of our services and ship them to a single datacenter which can then deploy these containers in a topographically agnostic way.

What we are currently stumped by is –

- Mesos doesn't seem to have any native support for MySQL
- Container based persistence seems awfully tricky and hard to manage/maintain.

We'd like to continue using MySQL/MongoDB/ElasticSearch because migrating to Cassandra etc. at this stage (we are a small team) is too much of an overhead and hence not an option.
What are the best strategies for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Mesos provide [Persistent resources support for storage-like services](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1554).

If you want to use MySQL on mesos, please consider try https://github.com/apache/incubator-cotton

Answer (score 0):

After some research we decided not to try [Cotton](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/cotton.html) but we're still sticking to deploying our services across a Mesos cluster.

Instead of hosting our own MySQL database, we decided to outsource it to Amazon RDS. But we're now faced with problems like doing something for our other databases like MongoDB.

Comment: Because Cotton too young?

Comment: How about consider deploy mysql/mongo db outside mesos cluster, and migrate them into mesos cluster when all conditions are satisfy.

Comment: @haosdent yeah, well, if we do manage to have a good experience with Amazon RDS, we have no reasons to migrate the MySQL database inside Mesos. Yes, utilisation wise, we're not going to heavily utilise the RDS instance too heavily right up front, but we'll see how to best optimise that. The problem still is deploying MongoDB across Mesos. Although, in our case , MongoDB isn't mission critical and can be containerised across the cluster, as long as the containers persist.

Comment: Thank you. Welcome any feedbacks about mesos.